# Stored procedure in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am working on Ruby on Rail web site and I am using MySQL for database support. Now I would like to know: is it possible to use stored procedure in my Ruby on Rails application? If possible can you provide some details?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google turns up some very useful info, including [this](http://nasir.wordpress.com/2007/12/03/stored-procedures-and-rails/).

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("execute procedure_name")
```

Comment: I asked a simple question is that can it be possible to use Stored procedure in ROR ? is it ok ? 
Thank you sir for answering . I got good help from the code and link u added in answer